# What is the difference between .tag and tag

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a query on this. Please look at the sample code below:

```
UIButton *button;    
button.tag = 1;
```

and

```
int but =  (int)[(UIButton*)sender tag];
```

The first line I set tag number 1 to button variable, using the .tag method. And in the second line, I used `(int)[(UIButton*)sender tag];` to extract and cast the sender into an integer value. My question would be, what is the difference between .tag and tag method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference. Before Objective C 2.0, the dot methods didn't exist; these were added, but they function as shortcuts to the longer bracketed call.

In your particular code example, in the first code block, `button` doesn't hold a pointer to a button. You'd need to call

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonRoundedRect];
button.tag = 1;
```

this would set the tag to 1. The second code block takes an existing button and extracts its tag to an `int`, as you indicated. A better example of parallel methods would be:

`button.tag = 1;` and `[button setTag:1];`, or

`int tag = button.tag;` and `int tag = [button tag];`

Comment: ah, I see... thanks! Regards to the first line, I simply cut it short because I wanted a brief explanation.. I asked this because I wanted to clarify the reason why I used it. Apparently I am stuck in a bind that I cant use this same method to solve a problem

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure! If this answer helped, would you mind hitting the check to accept it?